# DotNetOpenAuth RP fails behind SSL appliance

Tags: ssl, dotnetopenauth

I'm having trouble getting a DNOA RP working behind an SSL appliance (terminates the client HTTPS connection and reverse-proxies HTTP to the webserver behind it).

The problem is that the RP is incorrectly guessing the recipient endpoint from the incoming request (since it's *not* HTTPS by the time it hits the webserver) and comparing the endpoint with scheme on the return_to url (which *is* HTTPS)- it fails with the stacktrace below. I've spelunked around in the code a bit and I don't see a way to change this behavior without a custom build or a non-trivial subclass. I'm already passing the HTTPS version of the Realm and ReturnToUrl to OpenIdRelyingParty.CreateRequests()- that part's working fine.

Is it possible to fudge the detected recipient scheme to HTTPS or skip scheme comparison on a stock DNOA build, or am I patching up a custom build tomorrow?

---

Stacktrace:

```
ERROR DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging - 09 Jul 2010 00:11:39,450 - Protocol error: The openid.return_to parameter (https://XXX/Login.aspx?openid=XXX&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=XXX) does not match the actual URL (http://XXX/Login.aspx?openid=XXX&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=XXX&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=XXX&openid.response_nonce=XXX&openid.return_to=https://XXX/Login.aspx?openid=XXX&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=XXX&openid.assoc_handle=XXX&openid.signed=op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle&openid.sig=XXX&openid.identity=XXX&openid.claimed_id=XXX) the request was made with.
 at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ErrorUtilities.VerifyProtocol(Boolean condition, String message, Object[] args)
 at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Messages.IndirectSignedResponse.VerifyReturnToMatchesRecipient()
 at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Messages.IndirectSignedResponse.EnsureValidMessage()
 at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.MessageSerializer.Deserialize(IDictionary`2 fields, MessageDictionary messageDictionary)
 at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Reflection.MessageDictionary.Deserialize(IDictionary`2 fields)
 at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Receive(Dictionary`2 fields, MessageReceivingEndpoint recipient)
 at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.ReadFromRequestCore(HttpRequestInfo request)
 at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.ReadFromRequest(HttpRequestInfo httpRequest)
 at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.GetResponse(HttpRequestInfo httpRequestInfo)
 at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.OpenIdRelyingParty.GetResponse()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth has built-in support for SSL appliances when they add these special HTTP headers to the forwarded HTTP request: `X_FORWARDED_PROTO` and/or `HTTP_HOST`.  When these are present, the auto-detection of the outside-facing URL is correct.  If you can configure your SSL appliance to do this, that's probably the best option.

The alternative is to call `OpenIdRelyingParty.GetResponse(HttpRequestInfo)` instead of the overload that takes no parameters. You construct the `HttpRequestInfo` yourself using the outward-facing URL that you know is the real one.  Then the URL matching logic inside DotNetOpenAuth won't fail the request.

Comment: Perfect- thanks! I don't control the appliance for one of the RPs, but I'll definitely give it a try on the one I do (currently using a custom build with configurable scheme comparison).

Comment: Based on the code at https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/blob/master/src/DotNetOpenAuth.Test/Messaging/HttpRequestInfoTests.cs, I believe the protocol header should actually be HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO